# How to implement native android unity plugin?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am fresh in unity. What I have is - native android static lib that I use in my Android app by JNI. Now, I need to take this native android static lib and make it work in Unity as android plugin.

I would like to make it this way, in Android Studio build this lib with JNI interface (as I do now for this android project) and then use this lib buy JNI interface this way

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PluginTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    const string pluginName = "com.myapp.unity.MyPlugin";

    static AndroidJavaClass _pluginClass;
    static AndroidJavaObject _pluginObject;

    public static AndroidJavaClass PluginClass
    {
        get
        {
            if(_pluginClass == null)
            {
                _pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass(pluginName);
            }

            return _pluginClass;
        }
    }

    public static AndroidJavaObject PluginInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_pluginObject == null)
            {
                _pluginObject = PluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstance");
            }

            return _pluginObject;
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Elapsed time : {getElapsedTime()}");
    }

    float elapsedTime = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if(elapsedTime >= 5)
        {
            elapsedTime -= 5;
            Debug.Log($"Tick : {getElapsedTime()}");
        }
    }

    double getElapsedTime()
    {
        if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            return PluginInstance.Call<double>("getElapsedTime");
        }

        Debug.LogWarning("Wrong platform");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Like describes in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmNMugkOQBI

But as for me downside here is JNI implementation itself, for example if I need to call from Unity some method from native, so firstly I call method in c# , secondly this c# method call method in JNI and finally JNI call method in native.

I looks like that there is should be a way to build this native android lib in Android Studio without to use JNI and include this lib in Unity and use it directly from C# script.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are currently calling a native C/C++ function from Unity in this order:

```
C# -> Java -> C/C++
```

But you want to do this:

```
C# -> C/C++
```

If so, you can do the following:

If you have a function declared in C/C++ like so:

```
float FooPluginFunction () { return 5.0F; }
```

In your C# script you can then define the following:

```
[DllImport ("PluginName")]
private static extern float FooPluginFunction ();
```

Where **'PluginName'** matches the library name, and **'FooPluginFunction'** matches the function name in the library.
Calling the C# function, `FooPluginFunction()`, in your C# script will then attempt to call the C/C++ function. Ensure your library file is within the Unity Project.

For more information view the [unity docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html)